# Como pasar un parametro JSON en JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, json, api, cloud

tengo una duda y es que quiero acceder a una API que me devolverá un JSON, pero debo acceder con el siguiente parámetro:

```
ListMedia (String json_access, String 
json_media_filters)
"Lists the media to which the user has access in 
 the cloud platform."
```

ListMedia : Función.
json_access y json_media son los parámetros que le paso como json (en php con el json_encode)

En PHP lo tengo así y accede perfectamente:

```
$servicio="(Aqui va el link de la api cloud)";
$access['user'] = "(aqui va usuario)";
$access['password'] = md5("(aqui va password)");
$filters['type'] = "video";
$client = new nusoap_client($servicio, true);

$resp =  $client->call("ListMedia", 
array("json_access" => json_encode($access), 
"json_media_filters"=>json_encode($filters)));

$decoded = json_decode($resp);
print_r($decoded)
```

Y devuelve mostrando esto:

```
stdClass Object
(
[status] => success
[error] => 0
[data] => stdClass Object
    (
        [media] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 1552057437978
                        [name] => videoCorto.mp4
                        [original_name] => videoCorto.mp4
                        [file] => 3423e47523e07d4a62731f6506c1f64b.mp4
                        [src] => http://media.example.net/ec/3423e47523e07d4a62731f6506c1f64b.mp4
                        [origin] => nfs
                        [uploaded] => 2019-03-08 15:03:57
                        [modified] => 2019-03-08 15:03:57
                        [duration] => 0
                        [user] => 1548956206177
                        [size] => 1234124
                        [type] => video
                        [extension] => mp4
                        [hash] => 3423e47523e07d4a62731f6506c1f64b
                        [permissions] => 
                    )
                   )
                  )
```

Ahora PHP lo quiero dejar a un lado y quiero hacer la misma petición pero en JS. En la manera de hacerlo íntegramente en JS lo tengo así:

```
var servicio='(Aqui va el link de la api cloud)';
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', servicio);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send;
request.onload = function() {
  var medias = request.response;
  populateHeader(medias);
  showMedia(medias);
}
```

Pero obviamente no accede ya que no paso los parámetros de acceso ni el filtro(tipo vídeo) para que me devuelva el JSON y esa es mi duda.
Lo que sí tengo claro es que debo pasar los parametros en JSON como lo hago en PHP.

La documentación de como acceder a esa petición con los parametros que se le agregan (no hace falta todos, solo los principales como user/password y type)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tendrías que crear los parámetros y pasarlos en `send`, por ejemplo: `var params = 'user=TuUsuario&password=TuPass&type=video';`  y luego: **`request.send(params);`**  Para más detalles, [ver la doc de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send).

Comment: Buenas @A.Cedano he creado un nuevo post y creo que más claro a mi inquietud, si puedes le echas un ojo, gracias. [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/247315/webservice-con-node-soap-en-javascript]

Answer (score 2):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Para peticiones `GET`, tienes que pasar una cadena con los parámetros usando [el método **`open`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open), agreando a la URL los datos. Esto es debido a que las peticiones `GET` no tienen cuerpo, y por tanto no queda otra que pasar los datos en la URL.

El código debería quedar así:

```
var params = 'user=TuUsuario&password=TuPass&type=video';
var servicio='(Aqui va el link de la api cloud)';
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', servicio+"?"+params, true);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send(null);
request.onload = function() {
  var medias = request.response;
  populateHeader(medias);
  showMedia(medias);
}
```

Si fuese una petición del tipo `POST` (estas peticiones sí tienen cuerpo), entonces los parámetros se pueden pasar a través del [método **`send`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send), el cual admite precisamente un parámetro que sería el cuerpo de la petición:

```
var params = 'user=TuUsuario&password=TuPass&type=video';
var servicio='(Aqui va el link de la api cloud)';
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', servicio, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send(params);
request.onload = function() {
  var medias = request.response;
  populateHeader(medias);
  showMedia(medias);
}
```

Para más detalles puedes consultar también la pregunta [*How do I pass along variables with XMLHTTPRequest*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8064691/5587982) en Stackoverflow en inglés.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91279/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-como-pasar-un-parametro-json-en-javascript).