# Webservice con Node-soap en Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, nodejs, webservice, soap

Tengo un php el cual consume servicio web a una api usando la librería soap.
En PHP lo consumo así :

```
require_once "lib/nusoap.php";$servicio="http://cloud.ericsports.net/api/pac_service.php?wsdl";
$access=array();
$access['user'] = "user";
$access['password'] = md5("passworduser");
$filters['type'] = "video";

$client = new nusoap_client($servicio, true);

$resp =  $client->call("ListMedia", 
array("json_access" => json_encode($access), 
"json_media_filters"=>json_encode($filters)));
$decoded = json_decode($resp);
```

"ListMedia" es la una función en el api y "json_access" un parametro que pide usuario y contraseña y "json_media_filters" un parametro que pide el tipo de archivo que quieres consultar.

```
ListMedia (String json_access, String 
json_media_filters)
"Lists the media to which the user has access in 
the cloud platform."
```

Queriendo usar el servicio SOAP en JS tengo entendido que hay la misma librería y un formato como éste:

```
soap.createClient(url[, options], callback) - 
create a new SOAP client from a WSDL url. Also 
supports a local filesystem path.

var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://example.com/wsdl?wsdl';
var args = {name: 'value'};
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
  client.MyFunction(args, function(err, result) {
      console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Con el siguiente link que te indica:
[Node-js Javascript](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#soapcreateclienturl-options-callback---create-a-new-soap-client-from-a-wsdl-url-also-supports-a-local-filesystem-path)

Pero no tengo entendido como puedo meter los parametros que por ejemplo pongo en PHP, ponerlos en JS.

Comment: Esto habla concretamente de `Node.js`, que es por decirlo de alguna forma, Javascript como si fuera PHP. O sea, con `Node.js` puedes programar código Javascript para que se ejecute en el servidor. Para que eso funcione tu servidor debe soportar `Node.js`. Creo que deberías poner a tu pregunta la etiqueta de Node, así alguien con experiencia en esa rama podrá ayudarte mejor. Yo nunca lo he usado.

Comment: @A.Cedano Muchas gracias por el soporte ! saludos jefe!

Comment: Por lo que entiendo de tu pregunta deseas consumir el webservice desde un servidor Node ¿es correcto?

Comment: @MauricioContreras exacto, pero ya me dijeron que mi idea no era la correcta. Igualmente muchas gracias !